# got cannot resolve symbol error when adding new view to fragment programmatically

Tags: android

when I am writing a viewholder as the android guide described, I got error in the

```
  @Override
  public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    TextView v = (TextView) (LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            // here got error: cannot resolve symbol my_newly_added_view
            .inflate(R.layout.my_newly_added_view, parent, false));  
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
  }
```

as far as I know, here the method `inflate` accepts 3 parameters: int, viewgroup and boolean. and the int should be the "new view element id", so I just write down a newly id (`my_newly_added_view`) which never exists and totally new.

so I got this error.

any suggestions? thank you so much!

UPDATED:

so what does the XML file looks like?  is below correct?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="lalala-text"
        >

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting wrongfully to `TextView`, because the method returns data-type `View`.

Typically it would look alike this:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_newly_added_view, parent, false);
TextView test = view.findById(R.id.test);
```

The top-most node in a layout always needs to be some kind of layout.

Comment: so I updated my post, what does the xml file looks like ? thanks !

Comment: The XML seems to be fine, have extended the example a little based upon that.